TransferWise Sandbox accounts do call webhooks?
Is the 'Create a webook' functionality working in the test environment (https://sandbox.transferwise.tech/settings/webhooks)?
In the dashboard: When I 'Test the webhook' it says that 'Everything looks good!' but when creating it I get 201 Created and it brings me back to the 'Settings' page and in 'Developer tools' page it says that 'You don't have any active webhooks'.
